# @JsonProperty alternative in Spring Hessian

Tags: java, spring, hessian

I have a legacy Spring Boot Application using the HessianServiceExporter. The application uses serializable DTOs, which use a different naming convention than usual. This throws Sonar errors which I would like to solve similar to the @JsonProperty Annotation. The annotation does not work, which was expected.

```java
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String _uniqueName;
    private String _damageCategoryText;
```

Is there a way to rename these fields without changing the external representation?